# Cant understand checkerlog's(image attached) comment

Tags: java

Cant seem to understand checkerlog's(image attached) comment.

The output of the following code matches test cases expected output in **IDE** but fails test case 2.

[Link to problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1770/problem/A)

[Link to submitted solution](https://codeforces.com/contest/1770/submission/187353465)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Whiteboard {
public static long whiteboard(int[] a, int[] b) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    int k = b.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (k >= 0) a[i] = b[k--];
    }
    long sum = 0;
    for (long j : a) {
        sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    while (n-- > 0) {
        int a = s.nextInt();
        int b = s.nextInt();
        int[] whiteboardA = new int[a];
        int[] whiteboardB = new int[b];
        int p = 0;
        int q = 0;
        while (a-- > 0) {
            whiteboardA[p++] = s.nextInt();
        }
        while (b-- > 0) {
            whiteboardB[q++] = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(whiteboard(whiteboardA, whiteboardB));
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Cam you share the failure?

Comment: Well i have added the link to my solution you can check it out, the checker log comment is the failure it seems.